# How can I unblock the installation of a program in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, blocking

I want to install AllShare_2.1.0.12031_10.exe for my Samsung TV. Seems as if it is blocked somehow. What can I do about that?

[image]

Comment: Right click on the installer and select properties, see if there is an Unblock Button.

Comment: Done, comment was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to [download FileUnsigner](https://www.fluxbytes.com/downloads/).

Extract the rar file. Now all you need to do is open the `AllShare_2.1.0.12031_10.exe` file with `FileUnsigner`.

Simply Drag the `AllShare_2.1.0.12031_10.exe` file on FileUnsigner such that you get the `Open with FileUnsigner` pop-up.

[image]

You are done. Now you can run `AllShare_2.1.0.12031_10.exe` file.