# Windows 10's UAC prevents D-Link DWM-157's driver installation

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, modem, uac

I want to install a driver for my D-Link 3G USB modem under Windows 10.

Assumptions:

- I'm the only user on this copy of Windows,
- my account is a local administrator,
- I have lowered UAC to "do not notify me about anything".

After sticking my D-Link modem into USB port, nothing happens (on non-Windows-10 systems driver setup program is run automatically), but virtual CD drive with modem's drivers is created.

When I browse it and try to manually start `DriverSetup.exe` or `WirelessModem.exe`, I'm hit with an error message that Windows has blocked running this program and that I should contact an admin:

[image]

(*the above screenshot comes from below source, not from my actual device -- however the only difference in my case is a path / file origin pointing to a virtual DVD path, not to hard drive*)

This topic was risen on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/d-link-dwm-156-blocked-by-windows-10-build-10525/5321c5e0-eb89-4ed4-9d04-5618eacb8fe3) (for slightly different modem version), but no resolution was posted there. I don't have access to this device right now, thus I'll be able to try to apply steps mentioned in articles linked to above one only this evening.

Is there any constant explanation on why Windows 10 is blocking possibility to run software by the only user on particular system (who should install software )? Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @trejder Screenshots shouldn't generally be necessary, but in this case, the screenshot provides a data point that wasn't included in your original question: The part that says "Publisher: **Not trusted**". I'm not familiar enough with Windows 10 to tell you if that *is* the problem, but that's definitely where I would start looking. "Not trusted" is a much stronger term than "Unknown", which I think is what at least Windows 8 calls it when there is *no* signature on the executable in question.

Comment: This issue i believe caused by [D-Link private key that used to sign their drivers is leaked last time and revoked](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/18/d_link_code_signing_key_leak). To circumvent this, you could simply [remove the digital sign](https://superuser.com/a/1077504/534347) using [FileUnsigner](https://github.com/CooLMinE/FileUnsigner).

Answer (score 1):

[Alex's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1176939/156554) didn't bring me much help. Even after following it, my Windows 10 refused to run driver installation program, showing exactly the same error message (as in question).

By a complete coincidence I have noticed something strange. Even though I have purchased my D-Link DWM-157 just a month ago (January 2017) and even though latest firmware update for this model was around 15 months ago, it still has a very old firmware on-board:

- firmware installed: 1.0.7 CPG,
- latest [available firmware](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dwm-157-3g-hspa-plus-usb-adapter?revision=deu_revb#downloads): 2.0.3 EU.

So, I decided to update it. And that was the key turn-point in my case. Even though modem was not installed under Windows (driver installation failed, as in question) firmware updating software was able to detect it and install missing stuff. After firmware upgrade progress was over, I was able to run driver installation program (`InstallPackage.exe`) without any troubles.

*Note*: I wrote everything, what I've gone through. Though I don't know, if installing newest firmware did solve this problem or maybe it was just a coincidence.

Comment: You simply bought new item that was the distributors old stock.  The original executable on the disk wasnt signed.  Additionally your current configuration prevents unsigned and this untrustworthy applications from being executed.  If you disable SmartScreen you would be able to launch the original package (don't suggest you do that)

Comment: @Ramhound If by "disable SmartScreen" you mean solution provided by Alex then no, disabling it did not allow to execute original package -- as I wrote in a comment for his answer.

Comment: No, SmartScreen it is another M$ technology that basically filtering network connection... Let me clarify it in my answer since it could be profitable for someone who may step on that too

Comment: @trejder I updated my answer in case someone find it profitable

Comment: I was NOT talking about the filtering technology but the other feature also called SmartScreen.

Comment: @Ramhound If you're not talking about Alex's solution, but about something different, then why don't you post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to disable Windows driver signature enforcement.
It actually security feature since a lot of malware can keep it stealth if it hook system's API via driver.

To disable driver signature enforcement,
Start `cmd` as administrator and run:

```
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

and restart Windows after that

---

To reverse changes ( Enable Window's protection against digitally unsigned drivers ) you can run these commands (again - from elevated command prompt):

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

and restart Windows again to apply new settings.

P.S.

As it was mentioned by @Ramhound in comments, it could be another Microsoft technology called [SmartScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen) that scans network connections against blacklists and preventing installation because of that. If software tried to initiate some connections to its home and target links was on MS's blacklist then it possibly was blocked because of this, but to me it doesn't looks like a case because you was able to download new firmware and run the same software to upgrade D-link modem and issue was resolved with new firmware only.

According to screenshot in your question OS complaining to particular issue - software you tried to run isn't trusted. In my opinion it could be only three choices:

1. Software isn't digitally signed.
   ( But if you followed steps above to disable driver signature enforcement - this case should be eliminated )
2. Certificate that was used to sign digitally software was recalled or CA(Certificate Authority) that signed software isn't in certificate store anymore for bad behavior. (It could be a case)
3. Software (or driver to be correct) was incompatible with Windows 10
   and probably that was the case.

Many of such manufacturer keeps drivers for targeted operation systems inside of firmware to simplify process of installation on demand when it plugged in and the driver that comes out of stick was subject of those three cases I mentioned above.

Comment: I went through your solution (first part, i.e. disable integrity checks + system restart) twice, receiving confirmation that operation was successful each time. Running just `bcdedit.exe` gave me a dump confirming that `loadoptions=DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` and that `testsigning=Yes`, but there is no change in system behaviour. I see exactly the same error message each time I try to run `InstallPackage.exe` or `StartModem.exe` (the elevated way -- i.e. "Run as an administrator").

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game but in case someone wants to know. If you get the warning above and you know your app/driver etc is ok or you just insist on installing it anyway, enable the hidden administrator account, open elevated cmd and run **net user administrator /active:yes** log into it and then install. Be careful you have no restrictions and full access to the system. You won't be warned or prompted.